# How do i convert datetime which is in UTC using php/laravel like this format 2017-10-14T22:11:20+0000

Tags: php

I want to convert my date and time like this 2017-10-14T22:11:20+0000 with laravel.
In my DB I have saved date with a timestamp.
In laravel I have setup timezone as UTC.

I have tried,

```
$format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\+ZZZZ";
$datetime = new \DateTime($value);
return $datetime->format($format);
```

But is not showing the proper timezone.

Comment: If you use laravel, a datetime can be automatically converted to a Carbon object. (it's automatically done with created_at and updated_at timestamps). So to format have a look at their docs: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/. It also comes with an ->format function and their is a table for definitions.

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to achieve what you are looking for?

Comment: I have date like this which is in UTC with carbon 2020-09-25 12:02:15 need in this format 2017-10-14T22:11:20+0000

Answer (score 0):

```
 `$Parsedate = Carbon::parse($value,'UTC');
  $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $Parsedate);
  return $dateD = $date->toAtomString();`
```

Save your dates as UTC in DB using Carbon, with laravel. So, you can easily change the dates time with respective timezone.